# Weird css issue - What causes it to have top padding on a list

Tags: html, css

This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fuWjR/

The CSS is like this:

```
#pagination li { font-size:11px; }
#pagination li, #pagination-clean a { border:solid 1px #DEDEDE; margin-right:2px; }
#pagination .previous-off,
#pagination .next-off { color:#888888; display:block; float:left; font-weight:bold; padding:0px; }
#pagination .next a,
#pagination .previous a { font-weight:bold; border:solid 1px #FFFFFF; } 
#pagination .active { color:#00000 font-weight:bold; display:block; float:left; padding:0px; }
#pagination a:link,
#pagination a:visited { color:#0033CC; display:block; float:left; padding:0px; }​
```

As you can see from the example, the pagination steps down for each number. I want them all to appear on the same line. I can't see any top-padding in the example, so why is it doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

to the li items in the stylesheet, and make sure you have:

```
overflow: hidden; // or auto
```

for the parent ul

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your '#pagination li', this is the best option.

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```